# Alexandrov spaces which are not limits of Riemannian manifolds

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

**Are there important/ interesting/ natural examples of compact Alexandrov spaces with curvature bounded from below which are not Gromov-Hausdorff limits of smooth compact Riemannian manifolds with uniformly bounded from below sectional curvature?** (The condition of compactness might be relaxed somehow.)

EDIT: The dimension of manifolds in the approximating sequence is supposed to be bounded from above.

Comment: Can you get a tripod in such a way? (tripod is the 1-skeleton of the 4-vertices graph given by 1 vertex liked to the three others)

Comment: @YCor: Tripod has curvature bounded from above but not from below.

Comment: Ah OK (I saw "bounded from below" only in the second part of the sentence).

Comment: What about the metric suspension over $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Answer (score 6):

- There is an Alexandrov space, say $A$, with curvature $\ge 1$ which can not obtained as a limit of Riemannian manifolds with curvature $\ge \kappa$, if $\kappa>\tfrac14$; see "Metric constraints on exotic spheres via Alexandrov geometry." by Grove and Wilhelm.
- There is an Alexandrov space, say $A$, such that if it can appear as a limit of Riemannian manifolds $M_n$ with uniformly bounded curvature then $\dim M_n\ge \dim A+8$ for all large $n$; see ["Regularity of limits of noncollapsing sequences of manifolds" by Kapovitch](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0109075). It is expected that in this formula one can exchange $8$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Is the space $A$ compact in each example? In the second example, the curvature of $M_n$ is uniformly bounded from below or from both sides?

Comment: (1) yes always, (2) the construction is local and one can assume $A$ is compact,

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your answer. What is "yes always"? Is it related to the fact that the bounds on curvature are always lower, or that $A$ is always compact? Could you please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: in (2) you get examples which are compact and which are not compact.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (I am not an expert in the subject) a simple example (though using a highly non-trivial theorem) is given by considering the following example:
Let
$$\mathbb{S}^3\subset \mathbb{R}^4$$
be the round sphere of curvature $1$ and consider the isometry 
$\phi:\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{S}^3$ induced by
$$
(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\mapsto (x_1, -x_2, -x_3, -x_4)
$$
and let 
$$
X=\mathbb{S}^3/\phi.
$$
be the obvious quotient space with the natural quotient metric.
This quotient has curvature $\geq 1$, but is not a topological manifold (as small balls about $(\pm 1 , 0, 0, 0)$ look like cones over $\mathbb{RP}^2$).

Hence, by Perelman's stability theorem, $X$ cannot be the GH limit of smooth manifolds of curvature $\geq k$ for any $k\leq 1$.

Comment: The stability theorem concerns the situation when there is no collapse. In the situation of my question collapse is possible.